# How to make the value of a map blank while comparing it with the values of another map?

Tags: java, list, hashmap, linkedhashmap

Suppose I had a two maps region1, region2 and both are  declared as

```
LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> region1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> region2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

region1 contains the below values:

```
region1 : {R1 = [A, B, C, D]}
```

region2 contains the below values:

```
region2 : {R2 = [G, A, D, B]}
```

Considering the values of region1 as base values, iterate over the values of region2 and the non duplicate values must be placed in another map with the key of region2 and non duplicate value of region2.

So the map region3 contains

```
region3 : {R2 = [G]}
```

And we iterate region3 over another map comparing for the matched values

```
map1 : {1 = [G, C]}
```

Since there is match in the value, we need to add a blank space in the matched value.

So the map1 contains values

```
map1 : {1=[  , C]}
```

Comment: `map3 = new LinkedHashMap<>(region2); map3.removeAll(region1.keySet());`? With the values above, you will end up with `G` in `map3`.

Comment: `Considering the values of region1 as base values` - do you mean the R1 key or the values in the list associated with R1? I think it would be helpful to show what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: @Jason the values in the list associated with R1.

Comment: I don't understand, the maps have different keys. Do we have to iterate all possible entries?

Comment: @LppEdd yes we need to iterate all possible entries

Comment: Why are you comparing `R1` to `R2`?

Comment: @Karthik so, which one you ended up using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: optimized.*
`Stream` only. The original objects are not modified.
A little bit long, however.

```
final Map<String, List<String>> region1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
region1.put("R1", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D")));

final Map<String, List<String>> region2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
region2.put("R2", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "G", "C", "B")));
region2.put("R3", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "G", "C", "B")));

final Stream<Entry<String, List<String>>> entries =
        region1.values()
               .stream()
               .flatMap(values ->
                       region2.entrySet()
                              .stream()
                              .map(e -> {
                                  final List<String> value =
                                          e.getValue()
                                           .stream()
                                           .filter(v -> !values.contains(v))
                                           .collect(toList());
                                  return new SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), value);
                              })
               );

final Map<String, List<String>> result = entries.collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

And that is why I like `Stream`s. With *type inference* (`Java 10+`) it is even cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Without using streams, you can solve it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // setup the input and output maps
    LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> region1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> region2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> region3 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    region1.put("R1", asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
    region2.put("R2", asList("G", "A", "D", "B"));

    // for each key in region2
    for(String key : region2.keySet()) {

        // make a copy of the values for that key
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(region2.get(key));

        // remove all the duplicates from each of the lists in region1
        for (List<String> baseValues : region1.values()) {
            values.removeAll(baseValues);
        }

        // if there are any remaining list values
        if (values.size() > 0) {
            // put them into region3
            region3.put(key, values);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(region3);
}
```